# Insert word in html tag with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to inject an attribute (required) inside a `<input>` HTML tag with JavaScript. I need to insert it based on a radio button setting. So button on: insert "required". Button off delete "required".

Any ideas?

```
<input type="number" class="form-api" name="ne5" id="num_elec_5" size="20" placeholder="Electriciteit excl.">
```

Has to become:

```
<input type="number" class="form-api" name="ne5" id="num_elec_5" size="20" placeholder="Electriciteit excl." required>
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried something so far?

Comment: And what button should be pressed to make the `<input>` required? Also, that's not a 'word' you're adding, that's an attribute, or property, you want to set or unset based on an event taking place on an element you've apparently forgotten to show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code for adding and removing the required attribute.

```
input id="rYes" type="radio" name="YesNo" value="Yes" onclick="addAttr();">
<label for="rYes">Yes</label><br>
<input id="rNo" type="radio" name="YesNo" value="No" onclick="removeAttr();">
 <label for="rNo">No</label><br>

 <script>
 function addAttr() {
  document.getElementById("num_elec_5").setAttribute("required", "required");
 }

 function removeAttr() {
 document.getElementById("num_elec_5").removeAttribute("required");
 }
</script>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/SuyeP5O6Hjy5M4I2Tc47?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @deep. That saved me!

Answer (score -1):

If i have written dummy code in jQuery. Added two radio button. If first radio button is on, required text is inserted to input box else removed.

Html -

```
<form>
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-btn-1" class="radio-btn" name="test">btn 1
  <input type="radio" id="radio-btn-2" class="radio-btn" name="test">btn 2
</div>
<input type="number" class="form-api" name="ne5" id="num_elec_5" size="20" placeholder="Electriciteit excl.">
<button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

jQuery -

```
$('.radio-btn').click(function(){
    if($('#radio-btn-1').is(':checked')){
       $('#num_elec_5').prop('required', true);
   }
    else{
        $('#num_elec_5').prop('required', false);
  }
})
```

You can refer demo - https://jsfiddle.net/dhananjaymane11/ay8um6n4/